# @AssistedInjection RecyclerViewAdapter parameters resulting in error

Tags: android, design-patterns, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm working on a new android project using Dagger, and when I had to make an recycler view item trigger a click event I started having problems where to place my event, this event is pretty simple I'll just persist a new record on a realm database, however I'm using MVVM pattern then I should make my ViewModel do this kind of work, so this persistence logic should be away from my RecyclerView and ViewHolder, at this point I thought the best solution would be send the click event using my adapter parameters, and them I reach the point where my problem happens, when I try to send it using @AssistedInjection I'm getting the error below:

**tl;dr;**

> Send parameters to recyclerview adapter using @AssistedInjection are resulting in error

This is my error message:

```
error: The parameters in the factory method must match the @Assisted parameters in com.curuto.footballdata.view.main_activity.adapter.ChampionshipAdapter.
    public abstract com.curuto.footballdata.view.main_activity.adapter.ChampionshipAdapter start(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                                           ^
      Actual: com.curuto.footballdata.view.main_activity.adapter.ChampionshipAdapterAssistedFactory#start(io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection<com.curuto.footballdata.model.Championship>, android.view.View.OnClickListener)
    Expected: com.curuto.footballdata.view.main_activity.adapter.ChampionshipAdapterAssistedFactory#start(io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection<com.curuto.footballdata.model.Championship>, android.view.View.OnClickListener)
```

And here goes my code:

Adapter:

```
open class ChampionshipAdapter
        @AssistedInject constructor(@Assisted("championshipData") championshipData: OrderedRealmCollection<Championship>,
                                    @Assisted("donwloadDataClickListener") donwloadDataClickListener: View.OnClickListener,
                            ):
                                    RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Championship, ChampionshipViewHolder>
                                                                    (championshipData, true) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChampionshipViewHolder {
        val binding = RowItemChampionshipBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ChampionshipViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChampionshipViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(championshipData[position])
    }
}
```

Assisted Factory

```
@AssistedFactory
interface ChampionshipAdapterAssistedFactory {

    fun start(@Assisted championshipData: OrderedRealmCollection<Championship>,
               @Assisted donwloadDataClickListener: View.OnClickListener) : ChampionshipAdapter
}
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {


    lateinit var championshipAdapter : ChampionshipAdapter
    @Inject lateinit var championship: Championship
    @Inject lateinit var championshipViewModel: ChampionshipViewModel
    @Inject lateinit var championshipAdapterAssistedFactory: ChampionshipAdapterAssistedFactory
    @Inject lateinit var realm: Realm

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        //FootballDataApllication usa o compoente para ir injetando módulos nas atividades,
        //talvez Componentes diferentes devem ser usados em activities diferentes
        (applicationContext as FootballDataApplication).myComp.inject(this)


        val championshipData = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Championship::class.java).findAllAsync()
        val donwloadDataClickListener = View.OnClickListener{
        }

        championshipAdapter = championshipAdapterAssistedFactory.start(championshipData, donwloadDataClickListener)


        binding.rvChampionshipList.adapter = championshipAdapter
        binding.rvChampionshipList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)


        logD(championshipViewModel.retText())
        //binding.acbAddChampionship.setOnClickListener(this)


    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when(p0?.id){
            /*R.id.acb_add_championship -> {
                championshipViewModel.addChampionship("SUPER LIGA VIEW MODEL")
                logD("CLICKED ADD CHAMPS")
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to use the interface and View.OnClickListener in your ViewHolder?

Comment: The point here is, I don't really now, I want to use the proper patterns, with these frameworks, so I think the correct way is sending the events to my ViewHolder.